# Writing the result of a regexed document back to the document in python

Tags: python, regex, latex

I'm trying to create a python script to do a number of regular expression substitutions on a LaTeX document immediately before typesetting it, but I seem to be having some problem making the substitutions take effect. My script is as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, re, sys
tex = sys.argv[-1]
tex_file = open(tex, "r+")
tex_file_data = tex_file.read()

# DO SOME REGEXES
tex_file_data = re.sub(r"\b_(.*?)_\b", r"\emph{\1}", tex_file_data)
tex_file.write(tex_file_data)

# PROCESS THE DOCUMENT
os.system("xelatex --shell-escape " + tex_file.name)
```

Each time I attempt to process a document with this script, however, I get the usual `! Missing $ inserted.` error. According to the regular expression, these underscores were supposed to be replaced with suitable syntax. However, if I substitute the final line for `print(tex_file_data)`, the console will display the document with the changes having taken effect. As far as I can tell, the problem seems to be that the edited document is not being saved correctly, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

How might I fix this problem so that the script can be used to process documents?

**EDIT:** At @Yuushi's suggestion, I've editted the script as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, re, sys
with open(sys.argv[-1], "r+") as tex_file:
  tex_file_data = tex_file.read()
  tex_file_data = re.sub(r"\_(.*)\_", r"\\emph{\1}", tex_file_data)
  tex_file.write(tex_file_data)
os.system("xelatex --shell-escape " + tex_file.name)
```

However, I am still getting the `! Missing $ inserted.` error, which suggests that the original document is still being sent to the LaTeX compiler rather than the regexed one.

Comment: You're still missing a `seek`. I've edited my answer with a complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have two problems. Firstly, after a `read`, the stream is set to the end position, so you'll need to reset it to the start with a `tex_file.seek(0)` before you call `write`. Secondly, you never close the file, and the writes are probably buffered, hence you need a `tex_file.close()` at the end. Better still would be to use a `with` statement:

```
with open(sys.argv[-1], 'r+') as tex_file:
    tex_file_data - tex_file.read()
    tex_file_data = re.sub(r"\_(.*)\_", r"\\emph{\1}", tex_file_data)
    tex_file.seek(0)
    tex_file.write(tex_file_data)

os.system("xelatex --shell-escape " + tex_file.name)
```